# vulkan: SYNC-HAZARD-READ-AFTER-WRITE despite full pipeline barrier between operations

Tags: memory, synchronization, vulkan

I'm trying to use the synchronization validation of `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` in my vulkan application, but appear to be unable to "make it happy".
In the debugging process I've reduced the problem down to the a vkCmdDispatch -> [full pipeline barrier](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#full-pipeline-barrier) -> vkCmdCopyBuffer which (according to my understanding) should not result in a RaW-hazard.

An excerpt of the relevant part of the API dump is show below:

```
Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, pipelineBindPoint, pipeline) returns void:
    commandBuffer:   VkCommandBuffer = 0x5651fe89b9f0
    pipelineBindPoint: VkPipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE (1)
    pipeline:             VkPipeline = 0x5651fff4e5e0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR(commandBuffer, pipelineBindPoint, layout, set, descriptorWriteCount, pDescriptorWrites) returns void:
    commandBuffer:   VkCommandBuffer = 0x5651fe89b9f0
    pipelineBindPoint: VkPipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE (1)
    layout:         VkPipelineLayout = 0x5651fff4e270
    set:                    uint32_t = 0
    descriptorWriteCount:   uint32_t = 1
    pDescriptorWrites: const VkWriteDescriptorSet* = 0x7ffe711a6130
        pDescriptorWrites[0]: const VkWriteDescriptorSet = 0x7ffe711a6130:
            sType:           VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET (35)
            pNext:               const void* = NULL
            dstSet:          VkDescriptorSet = 0
            dstBinding:             uint32_t = 0
            dstArrayElement:        uint32_t = 0
            descriptorCount:        uint32_t = 1
            descriptorType: VkDescriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER (7)
            pImageInfo: const VkDescriptorImageInfo* = UNUSED
            pBufferInfo: const VkDescriptorBufferInfo* = 0x5651fea830b0
                pBufferInfo[0]: const VkDescriptorBufferInfo = 0x5651fea830b0:
                    buffer:                 VkBuffer = 0x5651ffcbf560
                    offset:             VkDeviceSize = 0
                    range:              VkDeviceSize = 1048576
            pTexelBufferView: const VkBufferView* = UNUSED

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdDispatch(commandBuffer, groupCountX, groupCountY, groupCountZ) returns void:
    commandBuffer:   VkCommandBuffer = 0x5651fe89b9f0
    groupCountX:            uint32_t = 1024
    groupCountY:            uint32_t = 1
    groupCountZ:            uint32_t = 1

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, pDependencyInfo) returns void:
    commandBuffer:   VkCommandBuffer = 0x5651fe89b9f0
    pDependencyInfo: const VkDependencyInfo* = 0x7ffe711a6280:
        sType:           VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEPENDENCY_INFO (1000314003)
        pNext:               const void* = NULL
        dependencyFlags: VkDependencyFlags = 0
        memoryBarrierCount:     uint32_t = 1
        pMemoryBarriers: const VkMemoryBarrier2* = 0x7ffe711a6130
            pMemoryBarriers[0]: const VkMemoryBarrier2 = 0x7ffe711a6130:
                sType:           VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER_2 (1000314000)
                pNext:               const void* = NULL
                srcStageMask: VkPipelineStageFlags2 = 65536 (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT)
                srcAccessMask:    VkAccessFlags2 = 98304 (VK_ACCESS_2_MEMORY_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_2_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT)
                dstStageMask: VkPipelineStageFlags2 = 65536 (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT)
                dstAccessMask:    VkAccessFlags2 = 98304 (VK_ACCESS_2_MEMORY_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_2_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT)
        bufferMemoryBarrierCount: uint32_t = 0
        pBufferMemoryBarriers: const VkBufferMemoryBarrier2* = NULL
        imageMemoryBarrierCount: uint32_t = 0
        pImageMemoryBarriers: const VkImageMemoryBarrier2* = NULL

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer, srcBuffer, dstBuffer, regionCount, pRegions) returns void:
    commandBuffer:   VkCommandBuffer = 0x5651fe89b9f0
    srcBuffer:              VkBuffer = 0x5651ffcbf560
    dstBuffer:              VkBuffer = 0x5651fe986280
    regionCount:            uint32_t = 1
    pRegions:    const VkBufferCopy* = 0x7ffe711a6090
        pRegions[0]:  const VkBufferCopy = 0x7ffe711a6090:
            srcOffset:          VkDeviceSize = 0
            dstOffset:          VkDeviceSize = 0
            size:               VkDeviceSize = 1048576
```

For reference, I've uploaded the full API dump [here](https://pastebin.com/0J1zY5je).

The synchronization validation reports the following.

```
SYNC-HAZARD-READ-AFTER-WRITE(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -455515022 - Validation Error: [ SYNC-HAZARD-READ-AFTER-WRITE ] Object 0: handle = 0x55eebfc30cb0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0xe4d96472 | vkCmdCopyBuffer: Hazard READ_AFTER_WRITE for srcBuffer VkBuffer 0x55eebfc30cb0[], region 0. Access info (usage: SYNC_COPY_TRANSFER_READ, prior_usage: SYNC_COMPUTE_SHADER_SHADER_STORAGE_WRITE, write_barriers: 0, command: vkCmdDispatch, seq_no: 1, reset_no: 1).
```

However, according to my understanding, the full pipeline barrier between the dispatch and the buffer copy (in command order) should avoid overlap between them also in execution order and with respect to memory visibility.

Notably, other validation areas (apart from "best practices") do not report any problems.

I'm at a loss what the validation error is supposed to tell me. Either I've made a very dumb small mistake which I cannot find, my understanding of synchronization is wrong or there is a bug in the validator.

Comment: Make a minimal example to verify your hypothesis, then report it if it is a validation bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a bug in the validation layers (present in version 1.3.236), that has been fixed in the latest release (1.3.239).